# Make Android Studio look like Intellij

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have been using AndroidStudio for a while and recently downloaded Intellij and noticed that the default settings on Intellij look a lot better than those on AndroidStudio (despite being apparently the same). 
[image: same file opened in both projects]
Even the setting pages look very different.

[image: differences in even the settings pages]

Studio is on the left and Intellij is on the right.

Is there a way to make Android Studio look like Intellij (they both seem to be using the same font, but the font in Intellij looks much fuller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is caused by the use of different JDK versions in recent versions of IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio. IntelliJ IDEA uses a custom JDK optimized for better font rendering on Linux machines.

Starting from Android Studio 2.2, AS will also bundle the same custom JDK as IntelliJ IDEA, and have the same look. (As of this writing, Android Studio 2.2 is available as a preview version.)